# How to store unique elements inside a JSONArray

Tags: java

I am trying to store only unique elements fetched from Database inside a JSONArray

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
JSONArray mainarray=new JSONArray();

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from categories");
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
    String T1 = rs.getString("T1");
    hs.add(T1);
    if(!hs.contains(T1))
    {
        mainarray.put(T1);
    }
}


System.out.println(mainarray);
```

Starngely the output is  an empty array []

By the way i am using `org.json.JSONArray`.

Could anybody please help .

Comment: The connection is required to establish before you can execute statements.

Comment: If this is your actual code (and not a simplified version) you can tweak your query to `select distinct T1 from categories`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 hs.add(T1);
 if(!hs.contains(T1)) { ...
```

The condition will always be false ... because you just added the element!

Therefore you will never add anything to `mainarray`.

---

For what it is worth, here's a fix for your bug:

```
// Inelegant version
if (!hs.contains(T1)) {
    hs.add(T1);
    mainarray.put(T1);
}

// Elegant version that avoids two probes of the hashset
// ... see javadocs for `Set.add` to understand why this works.
if (hs.add(T1)) {
    mainarray.put(T1);
}
```

Comment: @Kiran - that is true ... but irrelevant.  (And yes, of course I know that.  It is true of all `Set` classes.)

Comment: you mean i can't depend on that ?? , if not then whats the solution ??

Comment: No.  I don't mean that.  I mean you have a simple logic error in your program.  Please read my answer again.  The solution is obvious ... if you understand why your program is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your query and you need not handle duplicates in Java code.

```
JSONArray mainarray=new JSONArray();

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT T1 from categories");
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {
    String T1 = rs.getString("T1");
    mainarray.put(T1);
}
System.out.println(mainarray);
```